# How to reset recaptcha when using react-redux-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, react-redux-firebase

I am working with **React-Redux-Firebase**. I implemented **signing in with phone number**. Now I am trying to implement error handling. When number is invalid I display window alert with error message. The only thing left to do is to **reset recaptcha**. Without it, I am getting error:

> reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

I was trying to do according to Firebase documentation

> grecaptcha.reset(window.recaptchaWidgetId);
>
> // Or, if you haven't stored the widget ID:
>
> window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
> grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
> }

but it does not work in my code. I dont have `grecaptcha` implemented. I tried to add it with `react-grecaptcha`, but it did not work.

Could someone give me a hint **how to reset recaptcha after each error**, please?

```
  state = {
    phone: "",
    confirmationResult: {},
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    const recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      "sign-in-button",
      {
        size: "invisible",
      }
    );
    firebase
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(`+${this.state.phone}`, recaptchaVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        this.setState({ confirmationResult });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        // Handle Errors Here
        window.alert(`${error.code}, ${error.message}`);
        recaptchaVerifier.reset(); // How can I do that?
      });
  };
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! I'm not an expert with FIrebase but aren't you looking for the `.clear()` method? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier#clear

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. When I try `.clear()` I am getting error object:
`code: "auth/internal-error"
message: "RecaptchaVerifier instance has been destroyed"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert but from the documentation and by talking with you in the comment section I think you need to pass a `callback`. Like this:

```
const recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': function(response) {
    // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
   firebase
  .signInWithPhoneNumber(`+${this.state.phone}`, recaptchaVerifier)
  .then((confirmationResult) => {
    this.setState({ confirmationResult });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error; SMS not sent
    // Handle Errors Here
    window.alert(`${error.code}, ${error.message}`);
    recaptchaVerifier.reset();
  });
  }
});
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, you helped. The reason for my problem was that I didn't handle callbacks for recaptcha. I didn't fully understand documentation too, it was explained there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this problem for several days, maybe my answer will help someone.

```
    export const requestRecaptchVerifier = () => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        "recapcha-container",
        {
            size: "invisible",
        },
        auth
    );
};
```

I then call `signInWithPhone` from another function and handle the error like this:

```
        await signInWithPhone(formik.values.phone)
        .then(() => {
            // ... my code
        })
        .catch(() => {
            window.recaptchaVerifier.recaptcha.reset();
            window.recaptchaVerifier.clear();
        });
```

All the difference in

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.recaptcha.reset()
```

And

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.clear()
```